# RxJS delay switchMap new observable execution

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular project I'm making some HttpClient call and after response I need to check it's body and execute another HttpClient call or not, depending on first response. Also I need to delay some time the execution of second HttpClient call.

I can do it using `switchMap` operator but I would like to know **how to delay the second http call** in correct way.

Here is some very simple example:

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.execute().subscribe(r => console.log(r))
  }

  execute(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http1Call().pipe(switchMap((r) => {
     // Checking if 2d http call must be executed or not
      if (r === '1st call') {
        console.log('---Invalid 1st call, executing 2d')
        // TODO: Is that correct way to execute http2Call with delay ???
        return of({}).pipe(delay(3000), switchMap(() => this.http2Call()))
      }

      return of(r);
    }));
  }

  http1Call(): Observable<string> {
    return of('1st call').pipe(delay(1000));
  }

  http2Call(): Observable<string> {
    console.log('------Inside http2Call')
    return of('--------2d call response').pipe(delay(3000));
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem with the code you have now? You just want to know if there's a better way of doing it?

Comment: Why do you want to delay it in the first place? It sounds like a code smell.

Comment: @martin because before executing of second call I need to wait some time (backend requierement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is basically all right you can just simplify (or maybe make more obvious) the part where you make the delay:

```
return timer(3000).pipe(switchMapTo(this.http2Call()))
```

[`timer()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer) with one parameter will emit just once after the delay. You might also use `concatMap/concatMapTo` instead of `switchMap/switchMapTo` because in this case you'll never switch anything (`timer` emits just once and then complete).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Replacing `of({}).pipe(delay(3000))` with `timer(3000)` seams more accurate. Only one thing: using `switchMapTo` or `concatMapTo` produce immediate execution of `http2Call` so I still need to use `switchMap` or `concatMap`.

Comment: `switchMapTo ` will call the method but it won't subscribe to the Observable returned until `timer()` emits.